# Saving & restoring with Bundle

Tags: android

I've implemented saving (onSaveInstanceState) & restoring (onCreate) through Bundle. It works when activity is recreated due to the change of orientation but it doesn't work when activity is recreated after the other apps claimed resources. In this case it turns out that my data keys in bundle are absent. Why? I am at a loss.

Comment: What do you mean by "recreated from other apps claimed resources"?

Comment: I just lunch several apps without finishing mine and then return to my app. It is recreated then as far as i can see.

Comment: check onPause() and onResume() state of your app.

Answer (score 1):

The Bundle saved in `onSaveInstanceState()` and passed back in through `onCreate()` is not persistent and is only designed for saving state during configuration changes and Activity recreation during the lifetime of your app.

If your app is destroyed, as appears to be happening here, you will need to store your values somewhere persistent, for example in `SharedPreferences`

Use `onPause()` and `onResume()` to save and restore.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @user2251607 use shared preferences as suggested by Simon. +1

Comment: I wonder the bundle is not persistent. should rewrite this part. thanx. Can I use just preferences (not shared)?

Comment: Sure,  Use whatever makes sense.

Comment: Though, it's rather strange that the bundle i am getting in onCreate is not empty (isEmpty()) but without my values.Why? What does it contain?